# Dart - Class with Generic that extends a Second Class with a Second Generic - Is this possible?

Tags: generics, dart

Here is the code I would like to do:

```
abstract class StateBase<E> {
  void restoreState( E target );
  void saveState( E source );
}

class StateController<T extends StateBase<E>> {
  final List<T> _states = [];

  void takeSnapshot( E target ) { ... }
  void addState( T state ) { ... }
```

But in the line:

```
class StateController<T extends StateBase<E>> {
```

When I add the <E> bit it gives me the error:

```
The name 'E' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument.
```

Dynamic typing means I can get by with out the 'E' bit, and just use 'StateBase', but I'd prefer the type checking that I can get using the second generic E.

Is this possible to do in Dart?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `E` as another type parameter:

```
class StateController<E, T extends StateBase<E>>
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! And makes complete sense. Thanks so much! :)